# How to add additional HTTP response headers?

Tags: mapproxy, http-headers

I installed recent MapProxy (1.7.1) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS following [this guide](http://mapproxy.org/docs/latest/install.html). Everything works - I can get test OSM layer's tiles through proxy. But in order to use this layer on my web page I have to add additional response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my-domain
```

If found [headers](http://mapproxy.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#headers) option in the documentation but it's meant to

> add additional HTTP headers to all requests to your sources

but not response headers of proxy itself.

So my question is: **how can I add additional HTTP headers to my MapProxy's responses?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I opened an [issue](https://github.com/mapproxy/mapproxy/issues/160) on [github.com](http://github.com), and now one should be able to configure `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header using [access_control_allow_origin](http://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/configuration.html#access-control-allow-origin) option in `globals.http` section. This one is available since 1.8.0 (in nightly builds at the moment I answer this question). Thanks to MapProxy's developers.

Another way proposed in the [comment](https://github.com/mapproxy/mapproxy/issues/160#issuecomment-55608700) is to use additional dedicated HTTP proxy or any other HTTP server with proxy capabilities (like [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html)) in front of MapProxy with desired configuration of response headers. See [Deployment - HTTP proxy](http://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/deployment.html#http-proxy) section in the docs for details.